# Is a posteriori analytic philosophy just science?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, terminology, analytic-philosophy, analytic-synthetic-divide

Analytic philosophy primarily tries to solve problems *a priori*. Science can be considered to be synthetic *a posteriori*, based of some *a priori* theoretical framework. But would any conclusions that you come to (rigorously and objectively) through a posteriori analysis be considered scientific?

Comment: Can you give a citation for the claim "analytic philosophy primarily tries to solve problems *a priori*"? I'm not sure I buy that. Maybe it's because I'm a modern philosophy scholar -- not a contemporary analytic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "analytic philosophy" comes from the logical empiricists who thought (with Wittgenstein) that philosophy is pure a-priori language analysis whereas science is about confronting claims to the world a-posteriori.

Following this framework there is no such thing as "a posteriori analysis" because you need to be clear about what you mean before testing a claim empirically, so the analysis part has to be done a priori. Furthermore you don't need any empirical data to do language analysis and clarify what you mean.

Anyway, today this clearcut distinction between science and philosophy, or between a priori analysis and a posteriori synthesis, is often rejected (following Quine's critics, notably). Things are more complex.